# Proving that $(M\otimes _A N)_k=0\implies M_k\otimes _k N_k = 0$

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

I'm having some trouble proving the following implication: $$(M\otimes _A N)_k=0\implies M_k\otimes _k N_k = 0$$

I will explain the notation/assumptions shortly, I just want to note that this is an implication inside a bigger proof, so some of the assumptions I'm about to show may not be needed to prove this particular implication. The notation is as follows:

> Let $A$ be a commutative local ring, with maximal Ideal $\mathfrak m$. Let $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$ be the residue field and if $M$ is an $A$-module, define $M_k=k\otimes_A M \simeq M/\mathfrak{m}M$.
>
> Now, let $M,N$ be finitely generated $A$-modules. I want to prove that $$(M\otimes _A N)_k=0\implies M_k\otimes _k N_k = 0$$

I don't think that we need the fact that $A$ is local, $k$ is a field, or the fact that $M, N$ are finitely generated, as those seem to be useful later in the proof.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R \to S$ be a morphism of commutative rings and let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. Then
$$(M \otimes_R N)_S=S\otimes_R M \otimes_R N \cong M\otimes_R S\otimes_R N\cong M \otimes_R (S \otimes_S S) \otimes_R N \cong (S\otimes_R M) \otimes_S (S\otimes_R N)=M_S \otimes_S N_S$$

The isomorphism is explicitly described on elementary tensors as  $$s\otimes (m\otimes n) \mapsto (s \otimes m) \otimes (1 \otimes n)=(1\otimes m) \otimes (s \otimes n)$$

Comment: why is $M \otimes_R (S \otimes_S S) \otimes_R N \cong (S\otimes_R M) \otimes_S (S\otimes_R N)$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães the tensor product is associative (even if you mix different bases!) and commutative